# Can't store the values of longitude and latitude in my Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps

I have my own map, after signing in the map will display and then gets my coordinates (lat,long). I have put this code in an Override method onLocationChange(Location location) so that every time the user walks or moves anywhere the lat and long will be updated. The problem is I can't store the values in my Firebase.

```
try {


            DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

            model.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            model.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
            myRef.setValue(model, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Location.this, "Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Location.this, "Data saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude :" + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude :" + location.getLongitude() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Database(Firebase)

```
User{
      -KfBWefAFItacoMK5hF9{
                            email: "justinseneres29@gmail.com"
                            latitude: 0
                            longitude: 0
                            mobile: "09125516612"
                            name: "Phantom"
                            pass: "*********"


                          }

    }
```

Comment: At first, I suggest to not store any important data inside of a firebase node, until you are absolutely familiar with firebase database rules. (mail, mobile, passwords..). Next, what is the output of your log and toasts? Are you sure, that lat and lon are correct differ from zero? Then, try to use the updatemap methods, or you will always re-create the complete key-value entry set.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re the output of my toasts "Data could not be saved Permission Denied" and the values of the latitude and the logitude

Comment: Ah, that information was missing in your post :) Check your database rules. Go to firebase console, tab database and click on "rules". Now check that the rules are sufficient for your dev account. For test purpose, set rules to "read=true, write=true" and test again. Does is work now? (reset the rules afterwards)

Comment: @JacksOnF1re thanks sir , it works now. do you know how to call a nested node? just like from my database? because I want to store the values of the longitude and latitude  there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Permission Denied**

Ah, that information was missing in your post :) Check your database rules. Go to firebase console, tab database and click on "rules". Now check that the rules are sufficient for your dev account. For test purpose, set rules to "read=true, write=true" and test again. Does is work now? (reset the rules afterwards)

**Do you know how to call a nested node?**

Try to use the method `rootReference.updateChildren(Map<String, Object>);` for updating multiple nodes and childnodes at once. The Map contains `<KEY, OBJECT>` where `key` is a concatinated key like `"User/KfBWefAFItacoMK5hF9/latitude"` and `object` is the value you want to put in (here a float for latitude).

This approach has the advantage of updating specific key-value pairs in nodes, without updating the complete node. i.e you can update the mail value for a specific user, without overwriting the longitude and latitude.

You can also update a value directly by calling

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("your_root_here_or_empty");

ref.child("childNodeName").child("subChildNodeName").setValue(yourObject, yourListener);
```

I also can highly recommend to read: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Cheers

Comment: I tried changing the rules sir , my rules goes like this

`"Users":{
     ".read":true,
     ".write":true,
    "Name":{
     ".read": true,
      ".write":true,
    "name":{
      ".read": "auth!=null",
      ".write": "auth!=null"
        },
    "email":{
      ".read": "auth!=null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
      },
    "pass":{
      ".read": "auth!=null",
      ".write": "auth!=null"
      },
    "mobile":{
      ".read": "auth!=null",
      ".write": "auth!=null"
      },        
      
      }
    }
`